# ValueError: shapes (3,4) and (3,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to predict sales for a restaurant and used to following codes:

```py
my_model = str('sales + competition + population + income')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

my_model_fit = smf.OLS(y_train, X_train)

df['predict_sales'] = results.fittedvalues

print('\nProportion of Test Set Variance Accounted for: ',\
     round(np.power(df['sales'].corr(df['predict_sales']), 2), 3))

sites_data = {'sales': [0,0,0],
             'competition': [2, 3, 5],
             'population': [50000, 200000, 220000],
             'income': [25000, 220000, 190000]}

sites = pd.DataFrame(sites_data)

sites['sales_pred'] = results.predict(sites)
print('\nNew sites with predicted sales', sites, '\n')
```

But after the last code I received an error:

`ValueError: shapes (3,4) and (3,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)`

Could anyone help? I'm really desperate right now.

Comment: Most likely, you have to `.reshape(3, 1)` the object of shape `(3,)` at the line giving you the error.

Comment: can you provide sample data to replicate the issue?

Comment: In general you should show the full error trace.

Comment: Here you can find a link to the data

Comment: https://share-your-photo.com/c315bde33c

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't upload the csv. file @Yuca. Thank's I advance for your help

Comment: from your picture it seems that your data has information on the index, so your training data has 3 columns and `sites_data` has 4 columns, that for sure is going to give you problems